# Nuxt custom router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs

I'm trying to create a custom route in Nuxt with the following  `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
router: {
    base: '/',
    router: {
      extendRoutes (routes, resolve) {
        routes.push({
          name: 'custom',
          path: 'here-i-am',
          component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/Slug.vue')
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

Though, when I visit **localhost:3000/here-i-am** - it is throwing: `This page cannot be found.` I have created `Slug.vue` under the `/pages` directory.

Am I missing something else? I have tried to rerun the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. You currently have `extendRoutes` under a nested `router` property, which doesn't exist. Move it to the top-level `router` prop:

```js
router: {
  //router: {  // DON'T DO THIS
  //   extendRoutes() {...}
  //},

  extendRoutes() {...}
}
```

2. The path property must start with a leading slash for non-nested routes:

```js
routes.push({
  // path: 'here-i-am'  // DON'T DO THIS

  path: '/here-i-am'
})
```